# Exported three.js Blender models unnecessary smoothing

Tags: json, three.js, blender

This series of pictures illustrates my problem as clearly as possible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvPqQ.jpg

if you can't view the album or don't want to, the issue is that, when imported using the JSON loader, my exported blender models have extra smoothing.  Is it my code?

please view the album i can't put in images or link them yet.

I would like it to look like this:

```
    http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_horse
```

That looks exactly as it should.  here is my code:

```
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( "models/ref.js", function(geometry){
      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x606060});
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
      scene.add(mesh);
    });
```

Would something in my render-er code cause this?
here is the rest of it:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6592250/

Oh I should mention I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Maybe a stupid comment but.. have you tried to play with the modifier's settings ? like view/render here http://imgur.com/UGixV6W

Comment: I got it, I'm an idiot, I just had to add "shader: THREE.FlatShading" to the parameters of the material I was using on the mesh.  Thank you though.